# Accessing values created during a constructor - C++

Tags: c++, function, constructor

I have a question today about accessing variables whose values are created during an overloaded constructor. The functions i have return a variable, prefaced by either i (int) or ch (char).

I am trying to use a line like std::cout << FCalc.GetUserNum1(); within another function in order to print the proper value. As I have it now I am able to do so from my main, but I am not able to do so from other functions.

```
void vCalcNum();
char chGetUserOperation();
int iGetUserNum1();
int iGetUserNum2();
void vTestFunction();

FCalc FCalculate;
int main() 
{
    vCalcNum();
    //Overloaded constructor (Int, Int, Char) Each function returns variable
    FCalc FCalc(iGetUserNum2(), iGetUserNum1(), chGetUserOperation());
    std::cout << FCalc.GetUserNum1(); //cout prints proper value to console 


    sayUserOperation();
    return 0;

} 


void sayUserOperation()
{
    std::cout << FCalc.GetUserOperation(); 
    //This is where I am having trouble reffrencing GetUserOperation.
    // Class and getters are located in another file - can update if code is 
    //needed I have tried variants such as FCalculate.GetUserOperation() 
    //which returns nothing
}




//Edit to add FCalc.h source code

class FCalc
{
public:
    FCalc(); //constructor

    FCalc(int, int, char); //overlaoded constructor

    ~FCalc(); //destructor

    char GetUserOperation() const;
    int GetUserNum1() const;
    int GetUserNum2() const;


private:

    int NewUserNum1;
    int NewUserNum2;
    char NewUserOperation;




};

//edited to add FCalc.cpp source code
    #pragma once
#include "FCalc.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


char FCalc::GetUserOperation() const {return NewUserOperation;}
int FCalc::GetUserNum1() const { return NewUserNum1;}
int FCalc::GetUserNum2() const { return NewUserNum2;}

FCalc::FCalc()
{
    int UserNum1 = 0;
    int UserNum2 = 0;
    char UserOperation;
}

FCalc::FCalc(int UserNum2, int UserNum1, char UserOperation)
{
    NewUserNum1 = UserNum1;
    NewUserNum2 = UserNum2;
    NewUserOperation = UserOperation;
}
FCalc::~FCalc() {}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `FCalc` class.

Comment: `main` declares a variable named `FCalc`. `sayUserOperation` does not. So of course it is unable to call a method on some name that was never declared.

Comment: @BlakeLanders, please edit it into the question. It is vital part of the question.

Comment: Edited post to include FCalc.h and FCalc.cpp source code farther down - Apologies for the lack of quality formatting. I am new here :)

Comment: @BlakeLanders better formatting than some. :) You might be confusing yourself a bit by naming a variable the same as the class. You'll see that only an instance can call `GetUserOperation()` like `FCalculate`.

Comment: I think you are quite confused and have not yet grasped some of the fundamental concepts of c++. No matter though, its never easy at the start. I can see that you are trying to call `FCalc.GetUserOperation()`, but `FCalc` (the variable not the class), is only scoped to main, so outside of main you cannot access that variable. To solve this pass `Fcalc` (please call the variable something else like `fcalc`) to `sayUserOperation` as an argument, then you can access the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code defines a class `FCalc`. It also defines two objects of this class, `FCalculate` (global) and `FCalc` (local in `main`), confusingly named the same as the class.

If you want to access a variable in a function, the variable must be either global or passed in as a function argument. (This is nothing special about objects.)

Your `main` doesn't pass its local `FCalc` variable to `sayUserOperation`, so `sayUserOperation` can't access it. (What it sees instead is the *class* named `FCalc`, but that doesn't help you.)

Here's one way to do it:

```
void sayUserOperation(const FCalc &x)
{
    std::cout << x.GetUserOperation() << '\n'; 
}

int main() 
{
    vCalcNum();
    FCalc calc(iGetUserNum2(), iGetUserNum1(), chGetUserOperation());
    std::cout << calc.GetUserNum1() << '\n';
    sayUserOperation(calc);
}
```

---

The reason `FCalculate.GetUserOperation()` doesn't do anything useful is that even though the `FCalculate` variable is accessible, its contents are not initialized. In particular:

```
FCalc::FCalc()
{
    int UserNum1 = 0;
    int UserNum2 = 0;
    char UserOperation;
}
```

Your default constructor declares a few local variables, but doesn't do anything with them. It also doesn't set `NewUserNum1`, `NewUserNum2`, or `NewUserOperation` (the (weirdly named) member variables).

Comment: Apologies on the names of the variables/functions/classes. I ended up scraching and rewriting the code about a thousand times and these are the crappy ones I ended up with in the later version :) I was able to implement your code and get it to readback correctly. Thanks for the assistance! Now to actually understand what the changes are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the object of FCalc as argument to `void sayUserOperation()` function.
I think you have created a global object to be used `FCalc FCalculate`.

```
void sayUserOperation()
{
     std::cout << FCalculate.GetUserOperation(); 
}
```

Else, modify the function signature to:

```
void sayUserOperation(const FCalc &obj) //Send object as reference and use it
{
    std::cout << obj.GetUserOperation(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a class you can either have methods that belong to an instance
or you can have static functions that are independent of the 
instance i.e. doesn't have a "this" pointer.

When you write FCalc.GetUserOperation() you are not being consistent,
either write

```
FCalc foo(...)
auto ch = foo.GetUserOperation(); // calling the method on the instance foo
```

or declare `GetUserOperation` static

```
static char GetUserOperation();
...
auto ch = FCalc::GetUserOperation();
```

---

Your default constructor FCalc is not correct, you declare local variables and 
then initialize them there, they cease to exist once the constructor is left.

Instead you could write something like (before C++11)

```
FCalc::FCalc()
: NewUserNum1(0)
, NewUserNum2(0)
, NewUserOperation(0);
{}
```

in a similar manner you can write the other constructor as

```
FCalc::FCalc(int UserNum2, int UserNum1, char UserOperation)
: NewUserNum1(UserNum1)
, NewUserNum2(UserNum2)
, NewUserOperation(UserOperation);
{}
```

In general, member variables are declared with either a prefix `m_` or `_`
in order for it to be easier to see that it is an instance variable
and have Capital letters for types, but that is just my
preference.

Avoid also declaring global instances of your classes, it would be
enough in your main to declare the instance

```
FCalc foo(iGetUserNum2(), iGetUserNum1(), chGetUserOperation());
```

then passing it to sayUserOperation

```
sayUserOperation(foo);
```

by declaring the function like

```
void sayUserOperation(FCalc& f)
{
 ...
 auto ch = f.GetUserOperation();
}
```